# ASP.NET Core MVC Identity losing login after few seconds

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity

I have a problem with an ASP.NET Core MVC website.

I implemented Identity and everything is ok on my local development machine. After having published it I started experiencing a weird problem where the logged user gets logged out after a few seconds (or clicks).

I'm sure it's always the same server that answers to requests (not a web farm or load balancing problem). It's a simple Windows hosting. Don't know what else could I do...

---

EDIT 29/07/2018

I just noticed another thing. When user is logged in I see two empty cookies (`Identity.External` and `Identity.TwoFactorUserId`) that magically disappear after a few clicks when user is disconnected...

Another weird behavior: in the request before the forced user disconnection, application lags a bit and becomes slower, like it's loading something. I don't really know.

This is my `Startup.cs` `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddErrorDescriber<MultilanguageIdentityErrorDescriber>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
services.AddTransient<IEmailBusiness, EmailBusiness>();
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute())).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1); ;
services.AddOptions().Configure<SmtpOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("Smtp")).Configure<MailerOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("Mailer")).Configure<ShopOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("Shop"));
services.AddMemoryCache();
services.AddSession();
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
});
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(90);
    options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/account/logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/account/accesso-negato";
});
```

Comment: What response is the user getting back from the server? 401? Can you see the requests in the web server logs?

Comment: Is the cookie still there in the request where the user is not logged in anymore?

Comment: Using [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) you can see if the cookie is being sent with the request.  Also might help to share your startup code, have you modified the default settings?

Comment: Do you use token authentication or bearer? how do you calculate the expiration `TimeSpan` when user authenticate?

Comment: I just posted my Startup.cs. Hope it helps. I see the cookie is still there, but user is not authenticated anymore.

Comment: It might be an idea to add some logging, especially to [CookieAuthenticationEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationevents).  Do you have access to server event logs?  Could the application pool be getting recycled?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's a shared hosting machine with no access to event logs. I thought the same, but shouldn't the cookie be preserved?

Comment: It's possible that the keyring is being stored in memory, see [Data protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/#data-protection) & [Data Protection key management and lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/default-settings).  If that's the case, the cookie cannot be decrypted.

Comment: I was already in the right direction, but your comment was definitely the key to success! I used this library (https://github.com/adamrushad/AspNetCore.DataProtection.SqlServer) and no problems anymore! Thank you